# MySQL JOIN, UNION, both or neither?

Tags: mysql

In MysQL I am trying to obtain a certain result set, but am unsure what to research.

I have a 'people' table with:

uid(PK), firstname, lastname.

I then have a 'match' table with:

matchid, uid1(fk), score1, uid2(fk), score2

I would like the result set of my query to show:

matchid, fistname of uid1, score1, firstname of uid2, score2.

My beginner skills cannot seem to get it, 
my problem is with the second uid and showing the first name of that person as a column in the result set instead of the id.

I have tried, just as a test with the names and matchid:

```
 Select * From
    ( Select matches.idmatches, people.FirstName, 
      From people, matches 
      Where matches.uid1 = people.uid ) as a
    JOIN
    (Select matches.idmatches, people.FirstName, 
     From people, matches 
     Where matches.uid2 = people.uid ) as b
```

But it returns each name multiple times ( I had 6 entries and it returned 36 results...seemed to go through each possible combination) and the matchid does not match up:

```
uid1  matchid uid2 matchid
Michael 13  Jennii  13
Michael 14  Jennii  13
Michael 15  Jennii  13
Michael 16  Jennii  13
Michael 17  Jennii  13
Michael 18  Jennii  13
Michael 13  Jennii  14
Michael 14  Jennii  14
Michael 15  Jennii  14
Michael 16  Jennii  14
Michael 17  Jennii  14
Michael 18  Jennii  14
Michael 13  Jennii  15
...and so on...... you get the point...
```

what I want is:

```
    uid1 matchid uid2 matchid
    Michael 13  Jennii  13
    Michael 14  Jennii  14
.......and so on..... with no duplicates.
```

Hope that all makes sense, Just not sure first of all if I have made tables correctly, then if using a join is the correct method, and if so.. I do not really understand how I get this output, what am I doing wrong. Thanks heaps.

Comment: you want to use an inner join and a group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use:

```
SELECT matchid, p1.firstname AS firstname1, matches.score1, p2.firstname AS firstname2, matches.score2
FROM matches, people p1, people p2
WHERE matches.uid1 = p1.uid
AND matches.uid2 = p2.uid
```

Comment: Thanks heaps Jocelyn, this returned the result exactly as I asked above. I understand it, but do not think I would have worked that out for myself. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT 
  p1.firstname AS player1, m.score1, 
  p2.firstname AS player2, m.score2
FROM matches AS m 
INNER JOIN people AS p1 
  ON m.uid1 = p1.uid
INNER JOIN people AS p2 
  ON m.uid2 = p2.uid
GROUP BY m.matchid
```

You will get:

```
player1 score1 player2 score2
Alice   12     Bob     13
...
```

Comment: Hey Dmitry, This also returned the correct result. Thanks heaps for the response, helped me to understand.